# Apache Spark - Intersection of Multiple RDDs

Tags: scala, apache-spark

In apache spark one can union multiple RDDs efficiently by using `sparkContext.union()` method. Is there something similar if someone wants to intersect multiple RDDs? I have searched in sparkContext methods and I could not find anything or anywhere else. One solution could be to union the rdds and then retrieve the duplicates, but I do not think it could be that efficient. Assuming I have the following example with key/value pair collections:

```
val rdd1 = sc.parallelize(Seq((1,1.0),(2,1.0)))
val rdd2 = sc.parallelize(Seq((1,2.0),(3,4.0),(3,1.0)))
```

I want to retrieve a new collection which has the following elements:

```
(1,2.0) (1,1.0)
```

But of course for multiple rdds and not just two.

Comment: why do you want to intersect multiple rdds? and on what basis?

Comment: I think now my question is better to comprehend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
val rdds = Seq(
  sc.parallelize(Seq(1, 3, 5)),
  sc.parallelize(Seq(3, 5)),
  sc.parallelize(Seq(1, 3))
)
rdds.map(rdd => rdd.map(x => (x, None))).reduce((x, y) => x.join(y).keys.map(x => (x, None))).keys
```

Comment: That works, thanks. But if each collection had key/value pairs instead of integers that would not work, right? Also, this method uses a join. Usually, a hash partitioner is a good practice, right?

Comment: Should work as long as elements can be hashed. Unless you want some different output. Don't understand second question.

Comment: A good practice before using join between rdds is to use the Hash Partitioner to avoid redundant reshuffling and to make it more efficient. In your code you don`t use any hash partitioning.

Comment: Re-partitioning is shuffle by definition and join defaults to the optimal partitioner in the set.

Answer (score 2):

There is an [intersection method](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.html#intersection(org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD)) on RDD, but it only takes one other RDD:

```
def intersection(other: RDD[T]): RDD[T]
```

Let's implement the method you want in terms of this one.

```
def intersectRDDs[T](rdds: Seq[RDD[T]]): RDD[T] = {
  rdds.reduce { case (left, right) => left.intersection(right) 
}
```

If you've looked at the implementation of Spark joins, you can optimize the execution by putting the largest RDD first:

```
def intersectRDDs[T](rdds: Seq[RDD[T]]): RDD[T] = {
  rdds.sortBy(rdd => -1 * rdd.partitions.length)
    .reduce { case (left, right) => left.intersection(right) 
}
```

EDIT: It looks like I misread your example: your text looked like you were searching for the inverse behavior to rdd.union, but your example implied you want intersect by key.  My answer does not address this case.